# Can someone explain the recursive approach for the factorial function in Java?

Tags: java, recursion, factorial

can anyone explain how te concept of finding a factorial of a number is done with recursion...

Code is given below:

```
public class factorial {
    public static int calcfactorial(int n) {
        if (n == 1 || n == 0) {
            return 1;
        }

        int fact_nm1 = calcfactorial(n - 1); // (n-1)!
        int fact_n= n * fact_nm1;            // (n)!
        return fact_n;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = 5;
        int ans = calcfactorial(n);
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

I am struggling to understand the logic of the function calcfactorial.

I have tried many time to understand this but i am unable to grasp the logic.

Comment: "Play computer" with a pencil and paper: write down every step that happens. When it calls itself, indent your manual "logging". When it returns, un-undent. Or use a debugger, but IMO, doing it by hand will help more deeply.

Comment: What definition from math do you know for "factorial"? Does it not look exactly like the recursive function? If not, what differences do you see? I.e. please ask with more focus.

Comment: A recursive function will stack-up each _recursive_ call until the final result is evaluated—in this case it's `n == 1 || n == 0`—upon returning, every subsequent invocation will continue to it's next line.  It's similar to _fractal-geometry_.